# to and from in this sentence

Tags: meaning-in-context

Instead of saying "how long does it take to go from our house to the hospital and then from the hospital to our house"(all together) can I say "to and from" or are there other ways of saying that?

And is there another way of saying just from?

Comment: If you're currently ***at*** the house, and the hospital has already been mentioned in the conversation, neither location needs to be explicitly identified when asking *How long does it take to get/go **there and back**?* Which could also be expressed as *How long is **the round trip**?*

Answer (score 1):

The most natural way to say that would be, "How long does it take to get from our house to the hospital **and back**?"